# WHats the difference between MediaTemples Grid Server hosting and RackSPaces Cloud Server?

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I'm having huge issues with media temple. I have a grid hosting account signed up on media temple currently but am absolutely not ahppy at all with the services. To start with I've been getting too many Network errors and even to the point that I can't even run a wordpress installation without it dying out. Sometimes when executing a script thats a bit intensive the server just dies and I am prompted to download the php file being executed.

I'm looking at cloud server options by rackspace but before I get into this I'm a bit skeptical. I'm not very savy on what could computing is and how is it different from grid servers by media temple. INfact from teh definition of cloud servers and resources being distributed etc to handle spikes of traffic it sounds very simple to what mediatemples grid servers claimed to be.

Answer (score 0):

This can often be a personal brand preference.  All of these providers want to win your business and they will contend on offering solutions that meet an offer and a price to sign you up.  Finding out a little more about what you need will help scale out the right solution in the cloud.

You mentioned you are working with Wordpress so I am guessing this is a LAMP stack or possibly a PLAM, could be Windows.   If you are having troubleshooting problems with your CMS and that most of it seems performance based.   If this is mission critical and the core of your business then the best provider to select from which will be the one that has the most attractive SLA offer with a level of guarantee and what guarantee is availble.

SLAs can be as basic as ping, pipe, protocol or more specific to application layer and how much downtime is permitted.  Rackspace has an attractive cloud offer but their offer varies depending on what you are looking for and the price is not exactly cents as most of them advertise since your paid by the hour for memory usage among other things.

If you are looking for a few more recommendations I am more than happy to send some over to you.  Best of luck.

Comment: Please do, I've outlined the nature of applications I am running here - do send me information I'd really appreciate it. The Wordpress application is the mildest application I have hosted and I would most probably be looking for something which can handle something on lets say the likes of an ajax based web mail client plus document management system rolled into one.

Comment: Hi Ali, shoot me an email over to noneil@gmail.com and we can discuss.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about all the trouble you are having at (mt)Media Temple. We are constantly striving to improve our service and products, and always would like to know your exact problems in order to fix them. Can you please either contact me at mlebo@mediatemple.net or open up a Support Request so that we may further look into the problems that you are having.

Comment: I'm honestly at the end of my rope here, you only need to go through my support history to see my complaints which have been recurring - the only reply I would get is 'we checked your site and haven't faced any such issue as you are facing, outline the steps again' - I've even attached screenshots to prove the problem I'm facing but now I'm even facing problems with a simple wordpress installation...